# How to make the mouse move from the top to the bottom?

Tags: jquery

Html code

```
<div id="company-card" class="">
....
</div>

<div id="company-card-main" class="box-shadow" style="display: none;">
....
</div>
```

The mouse hover on the "#company-card" div, the bottom "#company-card-main" div shows when the  mouse out of "#company-card-main" and company-card-main div the content disappeared.

I am using the following code:

```
$( "#company-card" ).hover(
  function() {
    $("#company-card-main").css( "display", "block" );
  }, function() {
     $("#company-card-main").css( "display", "none" );
  }
);
```

Why can't the mouse move from "#company-card" to "#company-card-main" div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `hover` event for the element with id `company-card-main` too. Then only you can achieve the required effect. Additionally you can use `.show()` and `.hide()` for showing and hiding purpose.

Try,

```
$( "#company-card,#company-card-main").hover(
  function() {
    $("#company-card-main").show();
  }, function() {
     $("#company-card-main").hide();
  }
);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/NRs2Q/)